# Thymeleaf layout 404 not found

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I've installed all the dependencies and followed the tutorials, but the template isn't page with template isn't being load and gives me a: 
`404. Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

I've followed this page for installation: https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Installation.html

I'm running Thymeleaf 3.0.9 (dependencies installed) and version 2.3.0 ofthe thymleaf-dialect dependencies.

If I take out the `<bean></bean>` (found on the installation page) the page loads, without the template. This is the rest of the `config-mvc.xml` file that has the beans inside of it:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<!-- **************************************************************** -->
<!--  THYMELEAF-SPECIFIC ARTIFACTS                                    -->
<!--  TemplateResolver <- TemplateEngine <- ViewResolver              -->
<!-- **************************************************************** -->

<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

Am I missing something? I'm also using the latest version of the Spring-framework.

EDIT:

The controller I'm trying to reach:

```
 @Controller
 public class HelloController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        int temp = (Math.random() <= 0.5) ? 1 : 2;
        if(temp == 1)
        {
            model.addAttribute("template", "template");
        } else
        {
            model.addAttribute("template", "admintemplate");
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<display-name>Hello Spring MVC</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect">
    <constructor-arg ref="groupingStrategy"/>
</bean>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Edit: The model I send back does hold data ( seen through debugging ). A template name I give it, but it doesn't get put in between the ${}.

Comment: Your configuration seems OK. It's either that the path of your static content (pages) isn't configured in accordance with the mvc specification posted here, or your controllers aren't setup or registered correctly. Could you also post the code of the controller that isn't resolved correctly?

Comment: The configuration looks ok with or without the beans I left out? But isn't it odd then that the pages load just fine without Thymeleaf?

Comment: Is the `home.html` located in resources/static/ folder?

Comment: No, they are in "views". The config-mvc notes that it wil look in ```views``` so that's why.

Edit:
I tried putting them in ```static``` but it gives me the same outcome.

Edit edit:
They're in: resources/views

Comment: I deleted all the XMLs just now and it functions the way it did ( The thymleaf Standard URL Syntax doesn't function). For some reason, probably dependencies, Thymeleaf isn't converting the text into names. The ```layout:decorate="~{$template.html}``` isn't being.